# Union-like classes and variant members

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[class.union.anon]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.union.anon#4):

> A union-like class is a union or a class that has an anonymous union
>   as a direct member. A union-like class X has a set of variant members.
>   If X is a union, a non-static data member of X that is not an
>   anonymous union is a variant member of X. In addition, a non-static
>   data member of an anonymous union that is a member of X is also a
>   variant member of X. At most one variant member of a union may have
>   a default member initializer. [ Example:

In my first example below, class `C` **is not** a union-like class, but can we say that the members of the union subobject `u` are variant members of `C`? If the answer is yes, why?

```
struct C{  
    int i;  
    union{  
        int x;  
        char c;  
        float f;  
    } u;
};
```

In my second example, class `C` **is** a union-like class, but can we say that the members of the union subobject `u` are variant members of `C`? If the answer is yes, why?

```
 struct C{  
        int i;  
        union{  
            int x;  
            char c;  
            float f;  
        } u;
        union { int y; };
    };
```

Comment: According to your quote the answer seems to be "1 - no, 2 - no". Why do you think it might be different?

Comment: I think this paragraph is poorly written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the plain reading of the quoted paragraph, the answer is "no" to both questions.

The treatments of anonymous and named union members by the standard are quite different. For example, if `C` has variant members with non-trivial destructors, then `C` is responsible for somehow knowing which one to destroy (the compiler will not generate a default destructor for `C`), whereas if `C` has a member `u` that is a named union, then `C`'s destructor will simply call `u`'s destructor.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, but I believe [\[class.default.ctor\](2.2)](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#class.default.ctor-2.2) better answers the question(s), for it says (implicitly) that if a **non-union** class has a variant member, this variant member must be a member of an anonymous union, a data member of the class.